# How to transfer Github Gist to Repository?

Tags: github, gitlab, repository, github-flavored-markdown, gist

I am new to Github. I recently have created a **gist** https://gist.github.com/8d11e24576c94b2c07a9a48288082588.git and want to transfer it to my repository at https://github.com/Muhammad-Ammar-Masood/Log-In-Page.git.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler approach would be to clone your repository, and copy in it your gist, as a new file.
From there, add, commit and push.

Note that you can, from command-line, list your gists with [`gh girst list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_gist_view) and view the content of a particular gist with [gh gist view](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_gist_view)

```
gh gist view https://gist.github.com/8d11e24576c94b2c07a9a48288082588.git
```

(you need to [install `gh` first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation))

You can also, [since yesterday](https://twitter.com/github/status/1425505817827151872), do it online by going to your repository [`Muhammad-Ammar-Masood/Log-In-Page`](https://github.com/Muhammad-Ammar-Masood/Log-In-Page), and use [GitHub Codespace](https://github.com/features/codespaces) by typing <kbd>.</kbd>.
You can add your gist in the online VSCode there.

Answer (score 0):

You can, download Github Desktop on "https://desktop.github.com/", log in , create a new repository with GitHub Desktop, then choose a local directory on your PC for the newly created repository.

You can go to your Gist and choose to download as zip at the right end of the options
[Screenshot of Gist Url and the download button highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n5mm.png)

You can extract the zip file to your local directory assigned for the newly created repository.

On your GitHub Desktop : You can commit and push the changes of the repository to your GitHub.